# SDL Tridion Contract

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, sdl-tridion

Once an SDL contract is over, what happens to the current running site in Production? Will that stop working? Will the license file not work after that?

Is just taking a backup of the database sufficient, or is there any script I need to run to get all the content/binaries from the databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once SDL contract is over, what happens to the current running site in
> production? Will that stop working?

Yes (if the question tags are correct). But, even if it continues running, having it that way would be using unlicensed software which has legal implications. Contact SDL (RWS) directly to see what your options are.

**EDIT**

See also Nuno's comment below. It's based on your license type.

> Wondering just taking the backup of the database is sufficient or
> there is any script I need to run to get all the content/binaries from
> the databases. Please suggest.

Sufficient for what? All content including binaries, if managed through Tridion, are contained within your CM DB. Having a backup of said DB ensures that you have a snapshot of the CMS's data structure containing all the content.

**EDIT**
You can have binaries not in the CM database (but in for example Azure), but that was not an option in 2013 IIRC.

Comment: It actually depends on the contract. In some cases companies purchase the license to run Tridion software "forever", meaning that the license will not expire on any given day - but it will be bound to a certain hostname. I'd recommend OP to check with his Account Manager at RWS. At best, if you stop paying support, you will keep running the software and lose the ability to open incidents and receive patches.